# Sensors-detect is not detecting CPU core temp sensors

Tags: drivers, temperature, sensors

I have recently started using Ubuntu regularly and wanted a way to monitor my CPU temps.

I did the steps online of installing lm-sensors and doing sensors-detect.

This is the output for sensors-detect ->

> ```
> # sensors-detect version 3.6.0
> # System: Dell Inc. Dell G15 5515 [1.5.0] (laptop)
> # Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics (25/80/0)
>
> This program will help you determine which kernel modules you need
> to load to use lm_sensors most effectively. It is generally safe
> and recommended to accept the default answers to all questions,
> unless you know what you're doing.
>
> Some south bridges, CPUs or memory controllers contain embedded sensors.
> Do you want to scan for them? This is totally safe. (YES/no): 
> Silicon Integrated Systems SIS5595...                       No
> VIA VT82C686 Integrated Sensors...                          No
> VIA VT8231 Integrated Sensors...                            No
> AMD K8 thermal sensors...                                   No
> AMD Family 10h thermal sensors...                           No
> AMD Family 11h thermal sensors...                           No
> AMD Family 12h and 14h thermal sensors...                   No
> AMD Family 15h thermal sensors...                           No
> AMD Family 16h thermal sensors...                           No
> AMD Family 17h thermal sensors...                           No
> AMD Family 15h power sensors...                             No
> AMD Family 16h power sensors...                             No
> Hygon Family 18h thermal sensors...                         No
> Intel digital thermal sensor...                             No
> Intel AMB FB-DIMM thermal sensor...                         No
> Intel 5500/5520/X58 thermal sensor...                       No
> VIA C7 thermal sensor...                                    No
> VIA Nano thermal sensor...                                  No
>
> Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
> standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
> Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no): 
> /dev/port: Operation not permitted
>
> Some hardware monitoring chips are accessible through the ISA I/O ports.
> We have to write to arbitrary I/O ports to probe them. This is usually
> safe though. Yes, you do have ISA I/O ports even if you do not have any
> ISA slots! Do you want to scan the ISA I/O ports? (YES/no): 
> /dev/port: Operation not permitted
>
> Lastly, we can probe the I2C/SMBus adapters for connected hardware
> monitoring devices. This is the most risky part, and while it works
> reasonably well on most systems, it has been reported to cause trouble
> on some systems.
> Do you want to probe the I2C/SMBus adapters now? (YES/no): 
> Using driver `i2c-piix4' for device 0000:00:14.0: AMD KERNCZ SMBus
>
> Next adapter: Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter (i2c-0)
> Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
> Adapter doesn't support all probing functions.
> Some addresses won't be probed.
> Client at address 0x2c can not be probed - unload all client drivers first!
>
> Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 0 at ff00 (i2c-1)
> Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
>
> Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 2 at ff00 (i2c-2)
> Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
>
> Next adapter: SMBus PIIX4 adapter port 1 at ff20 (i2c-3)
> Do you want to scan it? (YES/no/selectively): 
>
> Next adapter: AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 0 (i2c-4)
> Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
>
> Next adapter: AMDGPU DM i2c hw bus 1 (i2c-5)
> Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
>
> Next adapter: AMDGPU DM aux hw bus 0 (i2c-6)
> Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
>
> Next adapter: AMDGPU DM aux hw bus 1 (i2c-7)
> Do you want to scan it? (yes/NO/selectively): 
>
> Sorry, no sensors were detected.
> This is relatively common on laptops, where thermal management is
> handled by ACPI rather than the OS.**
> ```

Even if I type yes for all questions, the end result is the same.

When I run sensors this is the output I get ->

> ```
> amdgpu-pci-0500
> Adapter: PCI adapter
> vddgfx:      718.00 mV 
> vddnb:       931.00 mV 
> edge:         +49.0°C  
> power1:      1000.00 uW 
>
> nvme-pci-0200
> Adapter: PCI adapter
> Composite:    +34.9°C  (low  =  -0.1°C, high = +82.8°C)
>                        (crit = +84.8°C)
> Sensor 1:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
> Sensor 2:     +38.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
>
> ucsi_source_psy_USBC000:001-isa-0000
> Adapter: ISA adapter
> in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
> curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)
>
> iwlwifi_1-virtual-0
> Adapter: Virtual device
> temp1:        +44.0°C  
>
> BAT1-acpi-0
> Adapter: ACPI interface
> in0:          12.38 V  
> curr1:         0.00 A**
> ```

Is one of the results displayed the CPU temp? Could someone please help me?

My system info ->

System: Dell Inc. Dell G15 5515 [1.5.0] (laptop)
Processor: AMD Ryzen 5 5600H with Radeon Graphics (25/80/0)
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Did you run sensors-detect with sudo?

Comment: Did you `sudo $(type -p sensors-detect)`? `sudo lshw `?

Comment: heynnema - Yes I did.

@waltinator - I tried the first command you asked, still same result. sudo lshw doesn't show all cores. It shows this for core info

-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0PGC5N
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: .DGWL0H3.CNCMC0017D0369.
       slot: Type2 - Board Chassis Location

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure Secure Boot is disabled**

I just ran into this issue and resolved it by disabling Secure Boot in my BIOS settings. If you haven't already tried running sensors-detect in root like others have mentioned, this may be why you're having this issue. Hope this helps :^)

Comment: But I need secure boot on